# PYDRIVE: is it possible to update the description of a PNG file when you update metadata?

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-drive-api, pydrive

I have a dataframe with the the file Ids and the content I want to put in the description. I'm using pydrive and this code works fine for txt files but gives an error when I try to update the description of PNG files. Thanks!

```
for ind in df.index:
    file1 = drive.CreateFile({'id': df['ID'][ind]})
    file1.Upload()
   # adding to existing description if any
    file1['description'] = file1['description'] + "\n" + df['Content'][ind]
    file1.Upload()
    print('description: %s' % file1['description'])
```

the error is: in **getitem**
raise KeyError(e)
KeyError: KeyError('description')

Comment: How about confirming the file ID again? Because when the file ID is not correct, also such error occurs. If the file ID is correct, can you provide the detail error messages?

Comment: The file ID is correct because it works for other metadata attributes like titile, etag, etc.

Comment: The full error is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>", line 57, in <module>
    file1['description'] = file1['description'] + "\n" + df['Content'][ind]
  File "<path>", line 137, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(e)
KeyError: KeyError('description')

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your error message, I couldn't replicate your situation.  This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to test it.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, I realized my mistake was I had to use the get function for description so I changed to file1.get('description'), and it worked!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.